# Horizontal Body Overflow on Windows but Not macOS

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following code to make an element span the full width of the page, expanding outside the limits of its parent width (detailed in this [CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/)):

```
width: 100vw;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
right: 50%;
margin-left: -50vw;
margin-right: -50vw;
```

It is working wonderfully as intended on all the main browsers on my Macbook Pro (Chrome, Firefox, Safari), but on all the same browsers on Windows 10, I am getting an annoying, very small overflow on the right side, creating an unwanted scroll bar.

Does anyone know why this is behaving differently in these two operating systems (browser agnostic)? It's pretty frustrating and I'd like to understand it and solve it with method rather than hackily adjusting fraction percentage values etc.

**Edit:** so it looks like this is the old issue with using the "vw" unit on browsers that have visible vertical scrollbars -- the vw unit takes the scrollbar into account thus giving some horizontal overflow. There are some workarounds but none simple or ideal. Seems like giving an overflow-x: hidden on your html root is the easiest, albeit not necessarily the most responsible way of solving this. Other solutions involve Javascript and saving the width of the scrollbar to a variable and excluding it with calc() from the 100vw. Not great!

Comment: Although I'm not a fan of using vw or vh, if I were you I'd check code inspector and see if I can pinpoint any margins that are showing through. I was able to reproduce what you are referring to and setting my body margin to 0 fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more than you posted, here is one thought: A `100vw` wide element will *not* fit into the browser window / cause a horizontal scrollbar if there is a *vertical* scrollbar, since the 100vw will be the width of the viewport including the space covered by the vertical scrollbar, making a horizontal scrollbar necessary to view the part behind the vertical scrollbar.

So if your viewport/screen on the Windows machine is maybe less high than on the Mac, causing a vertical scrollbar to appear, this is the cause for the horizontal scrollbar.